# Angular 5 app giving this error sometime :: Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_c188a8d396e6b8d23040 is not defined

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

This is my Angular 5 application using Visual Studio 2017 template with asp.net Core 2.0, but sometimes when I load the website it gives me error given below and when I reload again it works fine.

I was not able to resolve what it is.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_c188a8d396e6b8d23040 is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (..\..\external "vendor_c188a8d396e6b8d23040":1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:49)
at Object.<anonymous> (browser.js from dll-reference vendor_c188a8d396e6b8d23040:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:49)
at Object.<anonymous> (main-client.js?v=xKmK6Vxpt23YYFx6_zjZr6Q-eSRRcWv5QSFiYaGmpj4:34773)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:49)
at Object.hasOwn (main-client.js?v=xKmK6Vxpt23YYFx6_zjZr6Q-eSRRcWv5QSFiYaGmpj4:33559)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:49)
at bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:144
at bootstrap 7bd0582a9db11f64f883:144
```

Comment: "this is very urgent." is not a very useful informations to help us to address your problem. Instead maybe you could tell us if you have already search if it's a known error, if you're VS2017 version is up to date, exactly what template and browser you use, etc.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/717)?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i fixed this myself, actually i was using script async to load vendor.js, so i removed async and it works fine.